# Why does `\@outputpage` read as text in the code?

Tags: overleaf, syntax-highlighting

I have been given a document with some existing code. I would like to have laternating textheight on odd and even pages (to account for different footers). I'm new to LaTeX and don't know exactly what might be of interest.

Here is the code I thought would make alternating textheight on odd and even pages. But for some reason the `\@outputpage` in the code is reading as a string, as if I was trying to write "@outputpage" in the text, as shown in the screenshot.

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@outputpage{\textheight}{\ifodd\count\z@ 210mm \else 176mm\fi}{}{}
\makeatother
```

[image]

I don't know how to prevent this or if there is another way to create altering textheights. I am using Overleaf and I am starting to think the issue might be with this, rather than LaTeX.

Comment: You should make a complete example, remove all not related package. Not related to the question: you shouldn't use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and lmodern with lualatex.

Comment: It is hard to guess what you mean by "reading as a string" as Ulrike says we would need a complete example (you can almost certainly omit _all_ the packages from the example unless you can not show the problem without the package, try to help anyone tracing tex to debug your issue).  Note however that changing the text height depending on the parity of the page is inherently unstable: the text height is the main _input_ to the page breaking algorithm, but you are changing its effective value within the body of the page breaker. This is unlikely to have the effect that you want.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the code to show what the issue is. I don't think it's an issue with the code or compilation as such and the packages are possibly irrelevant. I am using Overleaf so the issue might be with this, rather than LaTeX.

Comment: That's simply an editor issue. Ask the staff at Overleaf.

Comment: You can see the same with `\z@`  where only the z is blue.  the syntax highlighting is optimised for in-document markup where @ is not part of command names. so teh colouring is slightly out but it has no effect on tex.

Answer (score 2):

This has no effect on latex it is purely an artifact in the editor.

Like most syntax highlighters the one used by Overleaf does not actually interpret the latex it just uses some fixed rules.

In a document, in the absence of `\makeatletter`

`\patchcmd\@outputpage{\textheight}{\ifodd\count\z@ 210mm \else 176mm\fi}{}{}`

woud be referencing the command `\@` followed by the 10 character tokens `outputpage`  and the command `\z` followed by the character token `@`

If you actually execute the latex then `\makeatletter` changes the tokenisation rules so that `@` is a letter so that `\@outputpage` and `\z@` are each single token command names, and that this interpretation lasts until reverted by `\makeatother` but the syntax highlighter does not know this.

You see the opposite issue on this site, which chooses to assume that `@` is always a letter, so that

```
\patchcmd\@outputpage{\textheight}{\ifodd\count\z@ 210mm \else 176mm\fi}{}{}
```

is highlighted as if `\@outputpage` is a command even though `\makeatletter` is omitted and this would fail for latex.